# How liferay know cas login success and auto login?

Tags: java, liferay

I have an issue as follows:

1. Assume I have been login success on Cas sever.
2. I open browser and access to liferay. Liferay can't not auto login. If want login I must click button login on liferay, liferay will redirect to Cas server. Cas server see user have login and send back to liferay.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to have these lines in your **portal-ext.properties**

```
# CAS Configuration
cas.auth.enabled=true
cas.import.from.ldap=false
cas.login.url=https://localhost:8443/cas-web/login
.logout.url=https://localhost:8443/cas-web/logout
cas.server.name=localhost:8080
cas.server.url=https://localhost:8443/cas-web
#cas.service.url=http://localhost:8080/c/portal/login
cas.logout.on.session.expiration=false
cas.validate.url=https://localhost:8443/cas-web/proxyValidate

auto.login.hooks=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.CASAutoLogin
```

These lines let you redirect fine between your localhost and your CAS server.

You have to have another file called **deployerConfigcontext.xml**. In this file you have to define the next *bean* and *list* of *registered services* to let your cas server go to your localhost and use the generated ticket.

**Bean:**

```
<bean id="serviceRegistryDao"
  class="org.jasig.cas.services.InMemoryServiceRegistryDaoImpl"
  p:registeredServices-ref="registeredServicesList" />
```

**List of registered services:**

```
<util:list id="registeredServicesList">
    <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService"
          p:id="1"
          p:name="jason web application"
          p:serviceId="^(https?|imaps?|http?)://.*"
          p:evaluationOrder="0" />
</util:list>
```

I also have several lines in the **cas.properties** file...maybe you need them too:

```
cas.securityContext.serviceProperties.service=http://localhost:8080/cas-web/services/j_acegi_cas_security_check
cas.securityContext.serviceProperties.adminRoles=ROLE_ADMIN     cas.securityContext.casProcessingFilterEntryPoint.loginUrl=http://localhost:8080/cas-web/login
cas.securityContext.ticketValidator.casServerUrlPrefix=http://localhost:8080/cas-web
cas.viewResolver.basename=default_views
```

**Files path:**

- %CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\cas-web\WEB-INF\cas.properties
- %CATALINA_HOME%\webapps\cas-web\WEB-INF\deployerConfigContext.xml
- %CATALINA_HOME%\portal-ext.properties